# C++0x: Slice template fails to compile with range-based for()

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I get the following compile error in gcc 4.6.1 when trying to get a Slice template class to work with range-based for() (occuring on the for() line with auto):

1. I know there is a slice class in boost - this is just for illustrative purposes
2. I managed to get ranged-based for() to work fine with a plain class - just having problems with a template class.

What am I doing wrong?

> sandbox.cpp:31:17: error: could not convert `‘(& t)->Slice<T>::Begin [with T = int, typename std::vector<_RealType>::const_iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >]()’` from `‘const const_iterator {aka const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >}’` to `‘std::vector<Slice<int>, std::allocator<Slice<int> > >::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const Slice<int>*, std::vector<Slice<int>, std::allocator<Slice<int> > > >}’`
>
> sandbox.cpp: In function `‘typename std::vector<_RealType>::const_iterator end(const T&) [with T = Slice<int>, typename std::vector<_RealType>::const_iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const Slice<int>*, std::vector<Slice<int>, std::allocator<Slice<int> > > >]’`

Code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template< typename T >
class Slice 
{
public:
    Slice( const vector< T >& v,
        typename vector< T >::const_iterator it0, 
        typename vector< T >::const_iterator itEnd ) :
        m_v( v ), m_it0( it0 ), m_itEnd( itEnd )
    { }

public:
    const typename vector<T>::const_iterator Begin() const
        { return m_it0;     }
    const typename vector<T>::const_iterator End()   const
        { return m_itEnd; }

private:
    const vector< T >&                         m_v;
    const typename vector< T >::const_iterator m_it0, m_itEnd;
};

template< typename T >
typename vector<T>::const_iterator
begin( const T& t )
{
    return t.Begin();
}

template< typename T >
typename vector<T>::const_iterator
end( const T& t )
{
    return t.End();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    Slice<int>  s( v, v.begin()++, v.end() );
    for( auto x : s ) 
    {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think I may have found my error:  I need to define begin() and end() with the signature begin( const Slice<T>& t ), etc...

...amazing how often the answer becomes obvious seconds after posting a question.

Comment: Try putting your stuff in a namespace so that ADL kicks in.

Comment: ty for your comment - I actually use namespaces in all my code, but stripped them out here for simplicity/clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `begin` and `end` template parameters are set up wrong.  They are passed `s`, which is `Slice<int>`, so `T` is deduced to `Slice<int>`.  The return type, then, is `vector<Slice<int> >::const_iterator`.  But `Slice<int>::Begin` returns `vector<int>::const_iterator`.

As you mentioned in your comment, the solution is to change the parameter from `const T&` to `const Slice<T>&`.  This way, `T` is deduced to `int` instead of `Slice<int>` and the return type becomes `vector<int>::const_iterator` like you want.

```
template<typename T>
typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator
begin(const Slice<T>& s) {
  return s.Begin();
}
```

However, if you change the name of your functions to `begin` instead of `Begin`, you can make use of `std::begin`, which has a more generic behavior:

```
template<typename T>
auto begin(const T& t) 
-> decltype(t.begin()) {
  return t.begin();
}
```

The range-based for statement has a special rule that ensures `std::begin` will be found by argument-dependent lookup even though your type is not part of namespace std. Less work on your part.

Comment: ty Dennis, for that excellent hint in the second half of your explanation.  As I was modifying my code, before seeing your comment, I was just wondering how I could abstract away the repeated begin() and end() definitions at the global scope.  Your answer was just what I was looking for.  - Ken

Comment: btw, any comments or answers which results in negative LOC is always greatly appreciated